# Creating a tab view much like Youtube's App

Tags: ios, objective-c

I'm trying to create an app that dynamically refreshes the information for tabs on the player page from a server in the exact same manner that the Youtube app does it for IOS. I'm unsure of where to begin since I'm really new to IOS programming. I've read some documentation but there seems to be alot of different ways to approach this. Any suggestions?

Comment: So you've "read a lot," but have you tried anything?

Comment: Just put the server request in `-(void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated` and every time you open that view it will refresh. Is this what you are asking?

Comment: Thanks Spire, that's what I was looking for and I will try to implement that into my code. I found a source code called fireUIPagedScrollView and I wanted to be able to retrieve data from the server on the tabs without disrupting the main page that is currently being viewed as the Youtube app does.